# How to set a textbox value in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

forgive me if this question is too silly .I'm studying Ember.js myself and I'm stuck with a problem I need to set a value of the textbox dynamically and I dont know how to do that now I'm using jquery for overcome this error by using `$("#results")[0].value = data;` and I know its not the right way How can I do the same in Ember,js

my Current code is given below

```
App = Em.Application.create();
App.BaseCurrency = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null
});
App.DestCurrency = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null
});
App.BaseSelector = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [
        App.BaseCurrency.create({ id: "INR", name:" Indian Rupee (INR)" }),
        App.BaseCurrency.create({ id: "USD", name: "US Dollar (USD)" })
    ]
});
App.baseSelector = App.BaseSelector.create();

App.DestSelector = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [
        App.DestCurrency.create({ id: "INR", name: " Indian Rupee (INR)" }),
        App.DestCurrency.create({ id: "USD", name: "US Dollar (USD)" })
    ]
});
App.destSelector = App.DestSelector.create();

App.ConvertCurrency = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    content: [],
    amount:0,
    baseCur: null,
    destcur: null,
    result: 0,
    convert: function () {
        var amount = this.get('amount');
        var from = this.get('baseCur');
        var to = this.get('destCur');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Home/ConvertCurenncy",
            data: "{amount:" + amount + ",from:'" + from + "',to:'" + to + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#results")[0].value = data;
            }
        });
    }
});

App.convertCurrency = App.ConvertCurrency.create();
```

and html

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    AMOUNT : {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="App.convertCurrency.amount"}}
    BASE : {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.baseSelector" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" valueBinding="App.convertCurrency.baseCur" }}
    DEST : {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="App.destSelector" optionLabelPath="content.name" optionValuePath="content.id" valueBinding="App.convertCurrency.destCur" }}
    <button id="btnConvert"{{action "convert" target="App.convertCurrency"}}>convert</button>
    RESULT :<input type="text" readonly=true id="results" />
</script>
```

Comment: can you show some code in a jsfiddle or jsbin how your setup looks like?

Comment: @intuitivepixel please look the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where almost there, what you might do is to customize a `Ember.Texfield`, for example:

```
App.ResultField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  type: 'text',
  attributeBindings: ['readonly'],
  readonly: true
})
```

and then use it like so:

```
Result: {{view App.ResultField valueBinding="App.convertCurrency.result"}}
```

then in your `success` callback you set `App.convertCurrency.result` to the received value:

```
...
success: function (data) {
  App.convertCurrency.set('result', data);
}
...
```

and bindings will take care on updating your textfield's value

Hope it helps.

Comment: You probably already know this, but Ember.TextFields are type "text" by default.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the hint, I know it but I wanted to be more verbose to help understanding that it can be defined explicitly :)